Rudin PMA 9.28. Why is $\phi(y)'k =(g(y)' k, k)$?
I am revising The implicit function theorem from Rudin's PMA as I forgot the entire proof of this theorem and I couldn't remember or understand why $\phi(y)'k =(g(y)' k, k)$ I didn't encounter this problem in the last time I read this theorem .
Here is the theorem (apologies for not writing the theorem but this would take too long to write):



Observe $$\frac{\Phi(\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{k}) - \Phi(\mathbf{y}) - (g'(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{k}
)}{\|\mathbf{k}\|} = \left(\frac{
g(\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{k}) - g(\mathbf{y}) - g'(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{k}}{\|\mathbf{k}\|}, \mathbf{0}\right)\to (\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0})$$ as $\mathbf{k} \to \mathbf{0}$. Thus $\Phi'(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{k} = (g'(\mathbf{y})\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k})$.

I still don't understand how to conclude that  $\phi'(y)k =(g'(y)k,k) $ can you explain that ?

@Mathematicsenjoyer  it follows from uniqueness of derivatives, Theorem 9.12 in Rudin's PMA.
